# Origin of a coordinate space

Tags: highcharts

I draw a coordinate space with the following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/digeti/edit?html,output)). What I don't understand, is why (-1.7, 0) isn't at the origin? It seems that the origin represents (-1.675, -0.25) at the moment, which is not what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <div id="container" style="height:400px;margin:1.5em 1em;"></div>

  <script>
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo:'container',
      type:'area'
    },
    credits: false,
    legend: false,
    title: { text:"" },
    tooltip: {},
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        color:'rgba(156,156,156,.9)',
        fillColor:'#ffffff',
        lineWidth:1,
        marker: {
          enabled:false,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled:false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      tickmarkPlacement:'on',
      categories:[-1.7, -1.65, -1.6, -1.55, -1.5, -1.45, -1.4, -1.35, -1.3]
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: { text: "x 10000", rotation: 0, y: 0, x:10, margin: -40, align: 'high'},
      tickLength: 10,
      tickWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickmarkPlacement:'on',
      gridLineColor:'#ffffff',
      categories:[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
    },
    series:[{  
        data:[[1,1],[1,3],[2,3],[2,1],[1,1]]
    }]      
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Highcharts automatically calculates extremes for both axes. If there's no value on the plot which is close to first category (`1.7` in your example) it's not used to set the minimum extreme. You can use `min` and `max` properties to set extremes manually:

```
xAxis: {
  tickmarkPlacement:'on',
  categories:[-1.7, -1.65, -1.6, -1.55, -1.5, -1.45, -1.4, -1.35, -1.3],
  min: 0,
  max: 8
};
```

I think using categories in this case is a **bad idea**. Categories are only an information for Highcharts how to format axis labels, data labels, tooltip etc. The actual y axis values for categories are their indexes in the array. So if you create categories like this:

```
categories:[-1.7, -1.65, -1.6, -1.55, -1.5, -1.45, -1.4, -1.35, -1.3]
```

they'll be treated as **Strings** and their numeric values are **0, 1, 2, 3...**

That means when you create a point with this options: `{x: 0, y: 5}` it'll be above `-1.7` category - it becomes very confusing.

You should manipulate numeric values on your axes using the following options (not `categories` array):

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval